# C program using pipes hangs when trying to terminate

Tags: c, operating-system, switch-statement, pipe, fork

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#define MSGSIZE 64

char msgbuf[MSGSIZE];

int main() {
  int p1[2];
  int p2[2];
  int nread;
  int choice = 0;
  pid_t child_a, child_b;
  if (pipe(p1) == -1) {
    printf("error in creating pipe\n");
    exit(-1);
  }

  if (pipe(p2) == -1) {
    printf("error in creating pipe\n");
    exit(-1);
  }

  child_a = fork();
  if (child_a == 0) {
    while (1) {
      dup2(p1[0], STDIN_FILENO);
      read(STDIN_FILENO, msgbuf, MSGSIZE);
      printf("%d receives message: %s\n", getpid(), msgbuf);
      close(p1[0]);
      close(p1[1]);
    }
  } else {
    child_b = fork();
    if (child_b == 0) {
      while (1) {
        dup2(p2[0], STDIN_FILENO);
        read(STDIN_FILENO, msgbuf, MSGSIZE);
        printf("%d receives message: %s\n", getpid(), msgbuf);
        close(p2[0]);
        close(p2[1]);
      }
    } else {
      while (1) {
        printf("<child_to_receive_msg> <message>\n");
        scanf("%d %s", &choice, msgbuf);
        switch (choice) {
        case 1:
          usleep(250);
          write(p1[1], msgbuf, MSGSIZE);
          break;
        case 2:
          usleep(250);
          write(p2[1], msgbuf, MSGSIZE);
          break;
        default:
          printf("Process does not exist");
          break;
        case -1:
          close(p1[0]);
          close(p2[0]);
          printf("parent waiting");
          wait(NULL);
          exit(0);
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

In the above program I have a parent making two child processes belonging to that same parent. The user writes to the parent process which pipes the message to be read by either child 1 or child 2. It keeps doing this continuously unless the user inputs -1.

The problem is that case in my switch statement doesn't get executed and instead the program hangs. I think I have my pipes closed at the correct places.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to start performing error checking. Check the man page of the calls you make. Add checks in your code to detect errors. When they return an error, use `perror` and `exit(EXIT_FAILURE);`.

---

Second, you need to start paying attention to the values returned by `read` and `write` since they could be less than expected. These need to be called in a loop.

For example, for `read`, you'd use the following:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <limits.h>

// Returns the number of bytes read.
// EOF was reached if the number of bytes read is less than requested.
// On error, returns -1 and sets errno.
ssize_t read_fixed_amount(int fd, char *buf, size_t size) {
   if (size > SSIZE_MAX) {
      errno = EINVAL;
      return -1;
   }

   ssize_t bytes_read = 0;
   while (size > 0) {
      ssize_t rv = read(fd, buf, size); 
      if (rv < 0)
         return -1;
      if (rv == 0)
         return bytes_read;

      size -= rv;
      bytes_read += rv;
      buf += rv;
   }

   return bytes_read;
}
```

It would be used something like this:

```
ssize_t bytes_read = read_fixed_amount(fd, buf, size);
if (bytes_read < 0) {
   perror("read");
   exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

if (bytes_read == 0) {
   printf("EOF reached\n");
   exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

if (bytes_read != size) {
   fprintf(stderr, "read: Premature EOF.\n");
   exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

---

Third, reading from the pipe will only return EOF once all file descriptors of the write end of the pipes have been closed.

Right after the fork, the parent should do

```
close(p1[0]); 
close(p2[0]);
```

Right after the fork, child 1 should do

```
close(p1[1]);
close(p2[0]);
close(p2[1]);
```

Right after the fork, child 2 should do

```
close(p1[0]); 
close(p1[1]);
close(p2[1]);
```

---

Fourth, there's this monstrosity:

```
while (1) {
   dup2(p1[0], STDIN_FILENO);
   read(STDIN_FILENO, msgbuf, MSGSIZE); 
   ...
   close(p1[0]); 
   close(p1[1]);
}
```

Really? Infinite loop. Attempt to repeatedly make STDIN a dup of p1[0]. Duping of a closed descriptor.

This should appear before the loop:

```
dup2(p1[0], STDIN_FILENO);
close(p1[0]);
```

Or you could skip those two call and simply read from `p1[0]` instead of `STDIN_FILENO`.

As for the infinite loop, it goes back to the second point. Check the value returned by `read`.

---

Fifth, you only wait for one child to finish, but there are two children to wait for. You need to call `wait` twice.

Comment: thanks I did what you suggested but the program still hangs when I put -1 in. It doesn't hang for the correct input, it sends and retrieves the messages correctly.

Comment: Does `read` returns 0 or -1 repeatedly (infinite loop), or does `read` block (not all descriptors to the write end of the pipe are closed)?

Answer (score 0):

You need to send some signal to your child process to inform then to terminate before waiting for them to exit. You should define some pre-defined message which means its time for child to terminate. Check below code. Here pre-defined message is `"-1"`. You should choose your own which doesn't conflict with your application's real data.

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define MSGSIZE 64

char msgbuf[MSGSIZE];

int main() {
  int p1[2];
  int p2[2];
  int nread;
  int choice = 0;
  pid_t child_a, child_b;
  if (pipe(p1) == -1) {
    printf("error in creating pipe\n");
    exit(-1);
  }

  if (pipe(p2) == -1) {
    printf("error in creating pipe\n");
    exit(-1);
  }

  child_a = fork();
  if (child_a == 0) {
    while (1) {
      dup2(p1[0], STDIN_FILENO);
      read(STDIN_FILENO, msgbuf, MSGSIZE);
      printf("%d receives message: %s\n", getpid(), msgbuf);
      close(p1[0]);
      close(p1[1]);
      if (strcmp(msgbuf, "-1") == 0) { // check if time to end
        break;
      }
    }
  } else {
    child_b = fork();
    if (child_b == 0) {
      while (1) {
        dup2(p2[0], STDIN_FILENO);
        read(STDIN_FILENO, msgbuf, MSGSIZE);
        printf("%d receives message: %s\n", getpid(), msgbuf);
        close(p2[0]);
        close(p2[1]);
        if (strcmp(msgbuf, "-1") == 0) {  // check if time to end
          break;
        }
      }
    } else {
      while (1) {
        printf("<child_to_receive_msg> <message>\n");
        scanf("%d %s", &choice, msgbuf);
        switch (choice) {
        case 1:
          usleep(250);
          write(p1[1], msgbuf, MSGSIZE);
          break;
        case 2:
          usleep(250);
          write(p2[1], msgbuf, MSGSIZE);
          break;
        default:
          printf("Process does not exist\n");
          break;
        case -1:
          strcpy(msgbuf, "-1");
          write(p1[1], msgbuf, MSGSIZE); // send message to end
          close(p1[0]);
          close(p2[0]);
          printf("parent waiting\n");
          wait(NULL);
          exit(0);
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```